# Content and Footer overlapping and not pushing footer to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can somebody pleaes tell me why my contentt and foter are overlapping and why won't the content push the footer to the bottom.

Along with these two problems, the background-overlay and background-gradient don't seem to actually be set to 100% for if the content expands to far, they just stop leaving the black background exposed.

I have its live version here: http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/

UPDATED:

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

body, html {
    position:relative; 
    border: 0px; 
    margin: 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #BCBCBC
}

#background-overlay {
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #273722;
    background-image: url(images/main-bg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0.0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#background-gradient {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(images/main-grad.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: top;
}

#header {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #555;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #555;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #555;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=40, Direction=0, Color='#555555')";
}

#header-image-grad {
    z-index: 300;
    transition:width 2s;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 608px;
    background-image: url(images/gray-trans.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000');

}

#header-image-border {
    z-index: 400;
    transition: width 2s;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 608px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background-image: url(images/border.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
}

.image-grad {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 600;
    width: 100%;
    height: 324px;
    min-height: 174px;
    max-height: 608px;
    background-image: url(images/header-img.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    top: 4px;
    left: 0;
}

.header-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 500;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    opacity: 0.0;
}

#header-container {
    z-index: 600;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-image: url(images/black-trans.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;                    
}

#navigation-container {
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 75%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#navigation {
    z-index: 1000;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
}

.nav {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;   

}

#body {
    transition: height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    width: 74%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 300px;
    background-color: #080908;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000');
}

#body-content {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
}

#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    background-image: url(images/black-trans.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#footer-content {
    height: 100px;
    width: 74%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    margin: 20px auto 20px;
    background-color: #96a381;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #10120f;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000');
}

/* STYLE ELEMENTS */

p {
    margin: 15px 0 15px;
}

.loading, .loading img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="background-overlay">
    <div id="background-gradient">
        <div id="header-image-grad">
                <div id="header">
                    <div id="header-container">
                        <div id="navigation-container">
                            <div id="navigation">
                                <span id="nav">Navigation Area...</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div id="header-image-border">
                <img class="header-img" src="slides/fields.jpg" alt="Panoramic Fields" />
                <div class="image-grad"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="body">
            <div id="body-content"></div>
            <div class="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading Content" /></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <br />
            <div id="footer-content">
                Footer Area...
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your footer is *inside* the "background-gradient" box, which is "position: relative".  Therefore the "position: absolute" offsets for the footer apply to that box, not the outer page.  These things are really easy to see using a diagnostic tool like Firebug or the Chrome developer tools.

Comment: How can I go about achieving a pushed footer while keeping them within the background containers? Also the background cotainers only stretch so far for some reason despite being set to 100% height.

Comment: Well if you want something to "push" the footer then it doesn't make sense for it to be absolutely positioned. You might want to start simple with a test setup on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com) or something.

Comment: Also I do know nothing about Firebug or Chrome Developer tools. Last time I was developing all we had was a validator and notepad. Lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` from `#footer`

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
    background-image: url(images/black-trans.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I've removed these now. I think my only problem now is gradient-overlay and gradient-gradient just stop repeating after the page stretches too far.

Comment: In which browser? It looks fine to me in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand what you need, but did you consider changing:

```
#footer-content {
            height: 85%;
```

to

```
#footer-content {
            height: 60px;
```

or simply try `overlay:auto;` or `overlay:hidden;` on both `#footer` and `#body`

Comment: The problem is the #body element is stretching under the #footer and #footer-content without pushing it down correctly.