# Keeping footer down with margin?

Tags: html, css

I pretty much see to have all the bugs figured out so far, besides one... the footer, again, isn't attached to the bottom. I had to remove the relative and absolute method because the content would stretch under the footer. So I need some sort of way to expand the area between the content and footer dynamically to keep the footer on the bottom. Is there a way this can be done? I have a "box-divider" set to 100% height, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Live code here http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/

**CSS**

```
            #body {
                transition: height 2s;
                -webkit-transition: height 2s;
                width: 74%;
                min-width: 1024px;
                height: auto !important;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #080908;
                 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
                box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
                /* For IE 8 */
                -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
                /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000');
            }

            #body-content {
                display: none;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #box-divider {
                width: 75%;
                min-width: 1024px;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 20px auto 20px;
            }

            #footer {
                width: 100%;
                height: 150px;
                background-image: url(images/black-trans.png);
                background-repeat: repeat;
                padding: 0 0 20px;
            }
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="background-overlay">
        <div id="background-gradient">

            <div id="header-image-grad">

                    <div id="header-container">
                        <div id="header">
                            <div id="navigation-container">
                                <div id="navigation">
                                    <span id="nav">Navigation Area...</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <div id="header-image-border">
                    <img class="header-img" src="slides/fields.jpg" alt="Panoramic Fields" />
                    <div class="image-grad"></div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div id="body">
                <div id="body-content"></div>
                <div class="loading"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading Content" /></div>
            </div>

            <div id="box-divider">
                &nbsp;
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <br />
                <div id="footer-content">
                    Footer Area...
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The term you are looking for is "sticky". A search for sticky footer will come back with a tonne of tuts.

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223774/content-and-footer-overlapping-and-not-pushing-footer-to-bottom Sincere advice: you should learn CSS+HTML instead of getting SO to solve _all of your issues_

Comment: Hey, Ejay, I am learning, hence the damn questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the many versions out there... i use one in my designs

[Sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)

This is what i do with my sites

```
html, body {height: 100%}

#wrap
{
    min-height: 100%;
}

#footer
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -58px;
    clear: both;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 85px;
    background-image: url(../images/footerBG.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

the negative top margin is what does the trick...

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="wrap"><!--for sticky footer-->

   <div id="headerWrapper"></div>

   <div id="navWrapper"></div>

   <div id="main">
     <p>this is where your content fun crazy shenanigans will go</p>
   </div><!--main or content-->

</div><!-- STICKY FOOTER -->

<div id="footer"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: I implemented the code but it did nothing to keep the footer down, and just stuck the foot at the direct bottom of the body. http://jordan.rave5.com/tmp/ I think the problem may be the use of the multiple page containers for the gradient and texture. I've tried four methods that do absolutely nothing, so something else is preventing the code from executing correctly.

Comment: you have to add a wrapper that the stickly footer will sit inside - just add an extra wrapper that wraps your whole page - all it will do is allow the footer to stick to the bottom of the page

Comment: I already have two with background-gradient and background-overlay. edit: Oh I think I see, thasnks for explaining!

Comment: Well I implemented just like the website shows, with no change still.

Comment: i added an example of what i used for my site

Comment: Huh. I just don't get it. No matter what it is in the same spot, always. Lol. Apparently I just don't need a footer.

Comment: your footer is inside your background overlay - take it out and create a new wrapper outside background overlay then apply my shown CSS

Comment: Hmm. I'll have to rework things. Those are the background gradient and texture over the black BG of the body (for the fade in)